# Why can't I populate and return my array created with rb_ary_new?

Tags: c, ruby

I'm not able to insert values into a Ruby array, and retrieve them later.

I put the results of different lines that I tried inside the first function. The results are:

```
VALUE rStraightCards;

static VALUE check_for_straight() {
    stuff...

    if (begin_straight != NOT_FOUND) {
        for (i = begin_straight; i >= end_straight; i--) {
           // this gives me a segmentation fault when I call straight_cards()
            rb_ary_push(rStraightCards, i);  

            // these lines give me an empty ary when I call straight_cards()
            // RARRAY_PTR(rStraightCards)[i] = i; 
            // RARRAY_PTR(rStraightCards)[INT2NUM(i)] = INT2NUM(i); 
        }
    }
}

VALUE straight_cards() {
    return rStraightCards;
}

void Init_straight_count() {
    rStraightCards = rb_ary_new2(NUM_CARDS);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both arguments for `rb_ary_push` are supposed to be of type `VALUE` but you're pushing an `int` (probably):

```
VALUE
rb_ary_push(VALUE ary, VALUE item)
{
    rb_ary_modify(ary);
    return rb_ary_push_1(ary, item);
}
```

Try this:

```
rb_ary_push(rStraightCards, INT2NUM(i));
```

I think it is worth noting that `VALUE` will usually be defined like this:

```
typedef uintptr_t VALUE;
```

So the usual warning flags for int-to-pointer conversions won't catch this sort of error.

Comment: Hi mu, sorry I left out of my question the fact that I had tried rb_ary_push(rStraightCards, INT2NUM(i)); and it returned the stack dump.  I edited my question now that I have pinpointed the nature of the problem.

Comment: @Jeremy: I don't know what you mean by "This returns a stack dump", do you mean that it is segfaulting? And `Qnil` is already a `VALUE` (`(VALUE)RUBY_Qnil` in particular) so pushing that onto an array should be okay.

Comment: Hmm, actually I had misdiagnosed my error.  It was an unrelated line of code that I had in there for debugging :(